# Android: how to use code to change layout_marginTop of textview?

Tags: android

After setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), I want to use code to change only layout_marginTop of textview(android:layout_centerHorizontal="true").

```
tvcity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
tvcity.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Centered changed to left-aligned.
setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) contains 4 parameters, but I only want to change the second parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tvcity.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: Then lp.topMargin = 100;

Answer (score 0):

Try using the existing margins:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(lp.leftMargin, 20, lp.rightMargin, lp.bottomMargin);
tvcity.setLayoutParams(lp);
```